# No Such Resource 404 error

Tags: python, html, twisted.web

I want to run index.html. so when I type localhost:8080 then index.html should be executed in browser. but its giving no such resource. I am specifying the entire path of index.html. please help me out.??

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File

resource = File('/home/venky/python/twistedPython/index.html')
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the difference between a URL ending with a slash and one without. It appears that Twisted considers a URL at the top level (like your `http://localhost:8000`) to include an implicit trailing slash (`http://localhost:8000/`). That means that the URL path includes an empty segment. Twisted then looks in the `resource` for a child named `''` (empty string). To make it work, add that name as a child:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File

resource = File('/home/venky/python/twistedPython/index.html')
resource.putChild('', resource)
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Also, your question has port `8080` but your code has `8000`.

Answer (score 5):

As per [this support ticket](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8022), the answer is to use `bytes()` objects when calling `putChild()`. In the original post, try:

`resource = File(b'/home/venky/python/twistedPython/index.html')`

And in the first answer, try:

`resource = File(b'/home/venky/python/twistedPython/index.html')
resource.putChild(b'', resource)`